# what are the differences between 'poco rall' , 'poco ritard' and 'poco rallent'

Tags: piano, sheet-music

from English translation seems similar so I cannot tell the diff.
i see this appear in one sheet music for one song. so want to get a better understanding of this.
thank you

Comment: It could be easier to answer more specifically if you could give the specific example of the song or sheet music.

Comment: the difference between ritadando, rallentando and ritenuto has been discussed here. already. there is no  difference between *poco* ... https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/pattern-identification-rit-followed-by-a-tempo/16953#16953

Answer (score 2):

*Rall.* and *rallent.* abbreviate *rallentando* which means "slowing down". *Ritard.* abbreviates *ritardando* which means "retarding". So both terms mean "gradually decelerating", perhaps suggesting the way you should do it.

*Poco* means "a little".

You may find this list useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Italian_musical_terms_used_in_English

Comment: "Oxford Companion to Music" (2002) also lists them as synonyms.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for checking. I suspect many composers use them interchangeably, though it's a bit weird when both appear in the same song.

Comment: @user1079505 Rall*e*ntando with an E please!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Grazie!

Comment: @use1079505 Thanks. And rall*e*nt with an E, if you'd be so kind! No wait! I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

They have *shades* of meaning.

```
The verb rallentare means to slow down. (Rallentare il passo is 
  to slacken one’s pace.)
The verb ritardare means to delay or to hold up (or defer).
The verb ritenere means to withhold or retain.
```

I agree with Laurence that *riten* usually indicates a fairly abrupt slowing-down or holding back. (A *ritenuta* is a deduction, eg. from your pay.) And *rall* and *rit* (*ritard*) are more gradual. A *ritard* is often followed by a return to the normal tempo or by a new tempo. *Rall* is often used at the end of a piece.

Answer (score 0):

Poco is 'a little'.   Rallentando (also abbreviated to rall or rallent) means a gradual slowing down. So does Ritardando (ritard).

There's also Ritenuto, which means a sudden change of tempo.   This can be unambiguously unabbreviated to riten.

But beware.   You'll see 'rit.'   This can be short for either Ritardando or Ritenuto!   Sometimes you have to make an educated guess which is intended.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t base this on any evidence I can point to which I can share. I can only tell you from asking composition professors this a couple times. I think ritardando is just a simple slowing down where as rallentando is a slowing down into the next tempo. Maybe check in a notation software manual. They can be surprisingly helpful in defining the differences in terms.